# query DB for unknown number of params

Tags: json, mongodb, express, object

Here is a simple express router, I want to give it query params and search the DB for them.

so, if the URL is like this `api?x=value1` the app should query the DB for `{ x:value1 }`

if the URL is `api?x=value1&y=value2`  the app should query the DB for `{ x:value1, y:value2 }`

Since I don't know the number of params in advance, I have created an empty object and appended it with the params if existed.

if there are no params I want to retrieve all documents in DB.

```
 .get(function (req, res){

      let update_issue= {};     /*empty object*/

      if(req.query.issue_title){update_issue["issue_title"] = req.query.issue_title}
      if(req.query.issue_text){update_issue["issue_text"] = req.query.issue_text}
      if(req.query.created_by){ update_issue["created_by"] = req.query.created_by } 
           /*append object if param exists*/

      if(Object.keys(update_issue).length !== 0 ){  /*check if that object is not empty*/
        db.collection('issues').find(update_issue, (err, data)=>{
          res.json(data);
          })
        }

      db.collection('issues').find().toArray((err, data)=>{
        res.send(data);
      })
```

this solution keeps giving me  `TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON`.

I understand that the object is in the form `{ x : "value" }` and it should be JSON object like this `{ "x": "value" }`

I tried flatted, JSON-stringify-safe still the same problem.

can you give me  a solution to this problem, or an alternative way to continue the work.

Comment: Can you do `console.log(JSON.stringify(data))` and see what it has? Also, post a sample input document of `issues` collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem using node package called Api query params.

here is my code:

```
var aqp = require('api-query-params');

 .get(function (req, res){

      let update_issue= aqp(req.query);    

      if(Object.keys(update_issue).length !== 0 ){  /*check if that object is not empty*/
        db.collection('issues').find(update_issue, (err, data)=>{
          res.json(data);
          })
        }

      db.collection('issues').find().toArray((err, data)=>{
        res.send(data);
      })
```

here is the package : https://www.npmjs.com/package/api-query-params